# I not getting open my custom file using intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, file, select, android-intent

I have a great problem to resolve on my app.

I'm try pick a custom file or content using the code below

```
public void openFolderToFile(Fragment fragment, String filter) {

        int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1; //101;
        int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)) {
            intent.removeCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        if (!intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)) {
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        }
        intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags()
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        // intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        // intent.createChooser(target, title)
        filter = filter == null ? "file/*" : filter;
        intent.setType(filter);
        // Uri uri =
        // Uri.parse(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getPath());
        // intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/nhpz,text/nhpz2");
        intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", filter);
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        /*
         * fragment.startActivityForResult( intent.createChooser(intent,
         * "Select your file"), PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
         */
    }
```

And this method can be used of this way...

```
String filter = "text/nhpz,text/nhpz2";
openFolderToFile(myFragment, filter);
```

or

```
String filter = "*/nhpz,*/nhpz2";
openFolderToFile(myFragment, filter);
```

The `String filter` could be any others custons extensions.

This code work fine, but in some devices when I try pick my custom file directly of download folder without using external apps my file cannot be selected.

I'm try any others combinations of similar codes, when you can see commented and the result is the same.

I can selected my file or content using externals apps during the process, but if I try selected directly of my sdcard or download folder I can't, and I need make this on my application, because I can not force the user to install an external application to use with my app.

Does someone have any idea to help me?

Comment: Use a real MIME type (comma-delimited lists are not supported in Android) or wildcard pattern (such as `*/*`, as `file/*` is non-standard). Remove `setFlags()`, as all of those flags are for *publishers* of content, not *consumers* of content.

Comment: Will I need grant root file access to work properly? If affirmative, how I do this programatically without using root apps to made this?